# CSS- Style "handles" above div without css absolute

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-gradients

I styled a "Calendar" div with "handles" above.

[image: calendat with handles]

This is created with setting 2 div 3*3 px with black background and placing them in absolute positions exactly above the top of calendar div inside a parent div which is position relative.

This calendar is located in absolute location above an image.

This works, but it feels very "hard coded" because every change in the calendar div will break the display because the "handles' would sill in the same place, while the calendar top border can move.

How can I get the same "handles" style on a top of calendar div itself so changes on the calendar CSS height won't effect the "handles"?

Comment: If your position is from left and right boundaries it will scale with the width. You could use percentages instead of px so it moves relative to width changes too if that's what you are after. Or maybe show an example of what happens when you change the div to your current style for a better idea of what your are trying to prevent.

Comment: @Danny the image changes according to screen size, and the design/size of calendar can change. So I prefer to look for a css solution that is different from 2 dots located. Maybe css gradient but I didn't find exotically how. Or different ideas

Comment: But what changes it? The content or the css, have different css apply to different breakpoints then?

Comment: the solution below solved it without the need to calculate the location at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [psuedo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) like so - see working example below.

The `.cal::before` element is a 3px tall box (`height`) with 3px black borders on the left and right.

It is absolute positioned off the parent calendar element by -6px on the Y axis (`top`) so it goes past the calendar's top border, and 3px `left` and `right` of the calendar bounds.

```css
.cal {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.cal span {
  /* day */
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.cal b {
  /* date number */
  display: block;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.cal::before {
  /* handles */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  top: -6px;
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
  border-right: 3px solid #000;
  left: 3px;
  right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cal">
  <span>SUN</span>
  <b>3</b>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="cal">
  <span>TALLER</span>
  <b>3</b>
  <b>4</b>
  <b>5</b>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like magic .cal::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  top: -6px;
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
  border-right: 3px solid #000;
  left: 3px;
  right: 3px;
} thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd do it with no extra element and a single `background` gradient (heavily commented code, you can also play with the the **[live demo](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/XWqawMd)**).

Below is just the relevant part, using Sass to make computations obvious as CSS variables aren't worth their performance impact in this case. The live demo linked above has the compiled code too in any case.

```
$g: .5em; // spacing between date components
$p: 1.5*$g; // calendar padding
$w: $g; // handle width
$h: $g; // handle height
$l: 2*$g; // lateral handle spacing

/* layout and stuff */
html, body, time, span { display: grid }

/* relevant code */
time {
    grid-gap: $g; /* spacing between date components */
    place-self: center; /* put calendar in the middle of parent */
    /* normal padding is $p 
     * and add handle height $h for the top padding */
    padding: $p + $h /* top */ $p /* lateral */ $p /* bottom */;
    background: 
        conic-gradient(at $w /* handle is $w wide */ $h /* and $h tall */, 
                transparent 25%, #222 0%) 
            $l /* spacing on the left of first handle */ 0/ 
            /* subtract from full padding-box width 100% the 
           * lateral spacing left $l + right $l + handle width $w */
            calc(100% - 2*#{$l} - #{$w}) 100%
}
```